# Fixing an element to the top

Tags: html, css

I have an element fixed to the top x, y axis. Is there any way how I change it to be fixed only to the x-axis? E.g. - so I would be able to scroll the fixed element to the left and to the right.

Current code:

```
<div style="position:fixed;top:0;width:2000px;">
The fixed header element
</div>
<div style="overflow:auto;width:2000px;">
the scrollable content element
</div>
```

Comment: I'm gonna assume you need `overflow-x` or `overflow-y`. Your question is not very clear.

Comment: I'm trying to make the 1st element (the one with position fixed) scroll to the left or to the right (y axis) whenever I scroll the website.

Comment: I don't think pure CSS can do this, javascript is a solution to meet your need.

Comment: Then - how can I do this with JS? Any suggestions?

Comment: try with `position:absolute;top:0px;float:left;`

Comment: Well, yes, the element gets positioned  to the top, but it's not fixed the top. E.g. - If I scroll the page down, the element disappears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a terrific question and CSS3 has no answer for you. There's no way to fix an element in one axis but not the other.

The ideal solution, imo, is to offer CSS3 attributes like, say, position:fixed-x and position:fixed-y. But there is no such thing.

The only way I know of to have this very useful behavior is to write JavaScript function to handle a setInterval( ) event; poll the current X or Y scroll position at each event; and, if the scroll position on the axis you want to fix has changed, then change the scroll position of the fixed element to compensate, i.e., to move it back to where it belongs.

I actually use this method and it works, but it's a pain. My code polls the X and Y scroll positions every tenth of a second, which is often enough to not look too herky-jerky.

You can see the solution at work [**in this long table**](http://www.sellmycalls.com/cgi-bin/chain). Narrow the window to make a horizontal scroll bar appear, the scroll the table left and right. The column heads move with the table but you can scroll the table body vertically and the column heads stay put.